# How to implement html2canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, screenshot, html2canvas

Ok, so I know this is a popular question, but none of the other questions, documentation, "tutorials", or anything else I've read has helped me to implement html2canvas. All of the instructions I've read have said things like 'here, paste this code, it worked for me' and then when I copy/paste the code nothing happens. At all. I don't even know where to begin to get this script to work on my page.

My site has graphics that a user can shift and rearrange at will, and I want them to be able to take an image of the unique arrangements that the user has created.

Here is my code so far.

```
//this code is all in my head tag
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script> 

//this was copy/pasted from the html2canvas examples website
<script>
        function html2canvas(document.body, {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            }
        });
</script> 


//and this is the button I have on my page that is supposed to call the function when the user clicks
<input type="button" onclick=html2canvas() id="pictureBtn" value="Take Picture">
```

I don't know how to use jQuery yet, but have the link to it in my head tag so that the html2canvas script can read it. I am primarily looking for a way to write everything I need in JavaScript, but if I must use jQuery then I will.

As a side note, I'd like the screenshot to be only of the area inside a single table cell or div with the child divs included.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you already tried to change onclick=html2canvas() into onclick="html2canvas()"  ?

Comment: @matthias_h I hadn't since none of my other functions required me to put quotes around them and they worked just fine. I did just try that in case it made a difference, but nothing else happened.

Comment: Don't know if that's an option - but have you just tried to check if your page renders with html2canvas on their testpage http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/screenshots.html ? In addition, not knowing your page - do you display svg-images there? Just asking as h2canvas doesn't render svg.

Comment: The testpage seems work alright. I have no SVG images. Only PNG.

Comment: Did you find a solution that worked for you?

Comment: @PKen No, I never did. I finally gave up on it and simply used the computer snip tool or print screen function.